# Question from Berkley Problems in Mathematics. Show that det($A$) > 0

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A = (a_{ij})$ be an $n\times n$ real matrix satisfying
the conditions:
$a_{ii} > 0$   $(1\leq i \leq n)$;  $a_{ij} \leq0$
$(i\not=j,1\leq i,j \leq n)$; $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_{ij}>0$ $(1\leq i \leq n)$. 
Show that det($A$) > $0$ .

Comment: Hint: Show that if $\lambda$ is a real eigenvalue then it is positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $A$ is [diagonally dominant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix) and so nonsingular.
Replacing off-diagonal entries $a_{i,j}$ by $ta_{i,j}$ for $0\le t\le 1$
also gives a diagonally dominant and nonsingular matrix $A_t$. But $A_0$
is diagonal with positive determinant. By continuity of determinant $\det A_t>0$ and so $\det A=\det A_1>0$.

Comment: A weakly diagonally dominant matrix may be singular.

Comment: @mlc There's nothing weak about these matrices!

Comment: \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -2 & -2  \\
    -1 & 6 & -1 \\
    -1 & -1 & 3  \end{bmatrix} what about this matrix; It's not a DD matrix. But confusingly, it is satisfying the question but not the result to be shown. I must be wrong somwhere.

Comment: @HirakjyotiDas one of your conditions is that the column sums are positive.

Comment: That's the very thing I was missing; Thank you

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown  I meant to point out that "diagonally dominant" alone does not imply nonsingular (as you state in the first line). This is potentially confusing to the OP (case in point: that's what happened). The argument uses also the assumption that the sum across columns is strictly positive.

Answer (score 1):

Here firstly $A$ is diagonally dominant. Secondly $A$ is $Z$-matrix as all its off diagonal entries are $\leq 0.$

Also diagonal entries are $> 0.$ Hence $A$ is a $P$-matrix. (All principal minors are positive).

So $\det(A) > 0.$

Comment: Good remarks, but you should mention references (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-matrix) and (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-matrix_(mathematics))

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, one can more generally see that from the [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem)